# Android TableLayout CustomRow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-view, android-custom-view

I am trying to make a day-calendar and for that I am using a tablelayout and I then want to define a custom row(layout xml) containing TextViews to be able to access data here is and example of my table layout:

```
    <TableLayout
  android:id="@+id/appointmentListView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TableRow 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unitNul"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="00:00"/>

        <CustomRow><\CustomRow> //this is where I imagined I would have to put my    custom element

    </LinearLayout>


</TableRow>
```

I would then proceed to put in appointments based on their time of the day in the correct rows (via. switch logic)

My questions are: 
How do I add a Custom element to each tablerow?
Is this the best way to do so?

side note:
I have tried to make a custom view element, but this seems to be a bit too dificult for me to handle. (this is also an option if you know a good guide explaining this)
I have already tried: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Comment: A/ use list view B/ if the amount of elements is dynamic, you cannot use xml. use java and addView

Comment: the problem I am facing with using a listview is that I need to have a textview to represent the time of day on the left side and my class values on the right which means I need to be able to specify where a specific element has to go. Ie. 12:15 needs to go to the row where the textview says 12:15 and so on. (I actually need to expand my item across several rows, but one problem at a time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create an Xml like this::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablerows"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1" >
        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

then in activity class dynamically add rows and the other views like this;;

```
    TableRow row;
    TextView t1, t2;
    int dip = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,(float) 1,             getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
   row = new TableRow(context);
   row.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams(android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
t1 = new TextView(context);
t1.setTypeface(null, 1);
t1.setTextSize(15);
t1.setWidth(50 * dip);
t1.setPadding(20*dip, 0, 0, 0);
row.addView(t1);
```

then in ur table(here "myTable") add the row like this::

```
myTable.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```